# Multiplatform software to block applications on the screen

Tags: open-source

I need a cross-platform software, preferably an open-source and a non-free one, which blocks an application on the screen for display, be it a browser or an application, to apply tests without the student having access to the others system features.

Does anyone have a simulate software?

Comment: From my perspective this sounds more to me that you need a better test concept instead of a (non-existing?) software that tries to prevent users GUI access to a software they have started.